# Exporting blender file with textures

Tags: textures, blender, 3d-modelling

Can any one give me an idea how i can export/share a .blend file in blenders with the textures? Baking textures is one way but i want to export the file without baking and all the textures.

thanx

Comment: Blender has several export options, some only need to be enabled in the addons preferences. What program do you want to transfer the data to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is simple, Blender has a packing option, which packs all the resources into .blend file.

"File"->"External Data"->"Pack All into .blend"

Sample link

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?194820-Pack-texture-in-Blender-2-5

Comment: Ok, then you can mark it as correct answer, that will help others. Click on the tick mark near the answers.

Answer (score 1):

As this link suggests, https://blenderartists.org/t/export-3ds-files-from-blender-with-attached-textures/674100

File naming should be simple and texture must be in same folder as your .blend file. If there is space in file name it may not work.

In general spaces in file names should be avoided.

Hope this helps ( anybody ) too.

Comment: link is broken as of 26 jan 2019 :(